# Selenium Grid Automation error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am trying to automate Node\Hub configuration process using Java code. For that, I get the code from the net and do the required changes in function and implement in my test code. While executing code I am able to open the firefox browser but before 
    myDriver.get("http://www.google.com") 
statement, execution fail and it showing Below error.

Can anyone have the solution for this?

Thanks in Advance.

```
 ERROR:
 2016-02-22 13:35:40.103:INFO:osjs.Server:jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
 2016-02-22 13:35:40.214:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:started  o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
 2016-02-22 13:35:40.237:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:Started SocketConnector@localhost:4444


    13:35:40.923 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 22.1-b02
    13:35:40.923 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
    13:35:40.943 INFO - v2.47.1, with Core v2.47.1. Built from revision 411b314
    13:35:41.140 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
    13:35:41.140 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
    13:35:41.285 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
    13:35:41.286 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
    13:35:41.289 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
    13:35:41.289 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
    13:35:41.293 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@51f9a96c
    13:35:41.293 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
    13:35:41.296 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:5555
    13:35:41.296 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@7fd61352
    13:35:41.308 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: http://localhost:4444/grid/register
    13:35:41.329 WARN - Max instance not specified. Using default = 1 instance
    13:35:41.338 INFO - Registered a node http://localhost:5555
    13:35:41.338 INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
    Main URL:------: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
    13:35:41.735 INFO - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, firefox_profile=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.F..., seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=firefox, version=44.0.2}]
    13:35:41.736 INFO - Available nodes: [http://localhost:5555]
    13:35:41.736 INFO - Trying to create a new session on node http://localhost:5555
    13:35:41.737 INFO - Trying to create a new session on test slot {platform=WINDOWS, firefox_profile=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=firefox, version=44.0.2}
    13:35:42.081 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, firefox_profile=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.F..., platform=WINDOWS, browserName=firefox, version=44.0.2}]])
    13:35:42.118 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, firefox_profile=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.F..., platform=WINDOWS, browserName=firefox, version=44.0.2}]
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
    \fxdriver@googlecode.com","installDate":1456148143480,"updateDate":1456148143480,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"size":8235030,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":true,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"3.0","maxVersion":"66.*"}],"targetPlatforms":[{"os":"Darwin","abi":null},{"os":"SunOS","abi":null},{"os":"FreeBSD","abi":null},{"os":"OpenBSD","abi":null},{"os":"WINNT","abi":"x86-msvc"},{"os":"Linux","abi":null}],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":0}
    1456148144037 addons.xpi    DEBUG  Updating XPIState for {"id":"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","syncGUID":"HmcHDpAIq3gI","location":"app-global","version":"44.0.2","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{"32":"icon.png","48":"icon.png"},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","installDate":1455253192222,"updateDate":1455253192222,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":24172,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"44.0.2","maxVersion":"44.0.2"}],"targetPlatforms":[]}
    1456148144038 addons.xpi    DEBUG  getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
    1456148144039 DeferredSave.extensions.json      DEBUG  Save changes
    1456148144039 addons.xpi    DEBUG  Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
    1456148144039 addons.xpi-utils     DEBUG  Updating add-on states
    1456148144041 addons.xpi-utils     DEBUG  Writing add-ons list
    1456148144063 addons.manager       DEBUG  Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1456148144064 addons.manager       DEBUG  Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
    1456148144064 addons.manager       DEBUG  Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
    1456148144064 addons.manager       DEBUG  Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1456148144065 addons.manager       DEBUG  Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
    1456148144066 addons.manager       DEBUG  Starting provider: GMPProvider
    1456148144076 addons.manager       DEBUG  Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
    1456148144077 addons.manager       DEBUG  Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
    1456148144077 addons.manager       DEBUG  Starting provider: PluginProvider
    1456148144077 addons.manager       DEBUG  Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    1456148144078 addons.manager       DEBUG  Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
    1456148144078 addons.manager       DEBUG  Completed startup sequence
    1456148144416 addons.manager       DEBUG  Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
    1456148144416 addons.manager       DEBUG  Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    1456148144416 addons.manager       DEBUG  Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
    1456148144543 DeferredSave.extensions.json      DEBUG  Starting write
    1456148144808 addons.repository    DEBUG  No addons.json found.
    1456148144808 DeferredSave.addons.json   DEBUG  Save changes
    1456148144813 DeferredSave.addons.json   DEBUG  Starting timer
    1456148144836 addons.manager       DEBUG  Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1456148144837 addons.manager       DEBUG  Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
    1456148144837 addons.manager       DEBUG  Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1456148144843 DeferredSave.extensions.json      DEBUG  Write succeeded
    1456148144844 addons.xpi-utils     DEBUG  XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
    1456148144878 DeferredSave.addons.json   DEBUG  Starting write
    1456148144894 DeferredSave.addons.json   DEBUG  Write succeeded

   at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
   at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:276)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:116)
   at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:223)
   at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
   at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:134)
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:103)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(DefaultDriverProvider.java:97)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    13:36:29.288 WARN - Exception thrown
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46'
    System info: host: 'TPR02', ip: '10.1.6.98', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_03'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the WebDriver is instanced twice and for this reason you are not able to open the browser after the driver is instantiated.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium version should be compatible with Firefox browser version. Try some different version of browser.